# Onmouseover change image border

Tags: html, css

I have a image inside a div and I want to change the border colour.

The html is

```
<div class="product-container">
  <a href="#"><img src="images/someimg.jpg"></a>
</div>
```

And the css is

```
.product-container:hover .product-container img{ border:1px solid red; }
```

Now this won't work. But if I do

```
.product-container:hover img{ border:1px solid red; }
```

Then it works. Now my question is that on hover product-container div any img will then have the same border. How can I tell specifically that I want the border on those images which are right under the product-container div.

Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Comment: Could you phrase your question to be more clear? I'm not entirely certain what you're trying to achieve. My gut feeling is that you're looking for `.product-container img:hover`, though that seems a bit too easy...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the border only of the image that's the immediate child of `product-container` div then you should use 
`.product-container:hover > a > img{ border:1px solid red; }`

`a > img` is needed because your `img` is inside a `href`. That's why `.product-container>img:hover` isn't working

```css
.product-container:hover > a > img{ border:1px solid red; }
```

```html
<div class="product-container">
  <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Many thanks for the explanation. That's what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

To say that this rule is only for the images with class .product-container, you should use

```
img.product-container:hover { border:1px solid red; }
```

what you have `.product-container:hover img{ border:1px solid red; }`

means that anything with the class `product-container` on hover and any image should have the 1 px red border

## Update

I actually misread the question you need the img to be a child of the class:
it will be  `.product-container>img:hover`

Comment: I tried with .product-container>img:hover but didn't work. For the first one you want the img should have class product-container. So it will be <img src... class="product-container"> ?

Comment: Instead if I do .product-container img:hover then it works.

Comment: the first solution the class has to be on img
the second solution the img has to be a direct child of class

Comment: if you want the image to be a child of `a` which is a child of `div` which has the class it should be .product-container>a>img